# XML Parse not showing elements with & symbol inside

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

Im trying to parse a xml feed in my app... The xml file is in this url

feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/TUvAW?format=xml

The problem is that when I access the description segment it diplays different special symbols such as quotation marks. This is one of the descripton segments im trying to parse from my xml:

```
<description>Este es mi blog 3&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/blogspot/TUvAW/~4/URCV9ModTR0" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
```

Im parsing it with the NSXMLParser, these are the method I'm using in my:

XMLParser.m

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        currentFeed = [Feed alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"author"])
    {
        isStatus = NO;
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if (isStatus)
    {
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"description"])
        {
            currentFeed.description = currentNodeContent;
            NSLog(@"%@",currentNodeContent);

        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"])
        {
            currentFeed.content = currentNodeContent;
            NSLog(@"%@",currentNodeContent);

        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"link"])
        {
            currentFeed.WVUrl = currentNodeContent;
            NSLog(@"%@",currentNodeContent);
        }
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        [self.feeds addObject:currentFeed];
        currentFeed = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}
```

Im using those NSLogs to track the strings that Im getting from the parse but my description node content is always showing just this : >
The title and link nodes are displaying perfectly.

I want to get all that string from the description node to use it later but simply I can't, I dont know whats going wrong with this.

Comment: You need to HTML-unescape the strings, that's all.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but could you explain me how to do that?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no built-in method for that in Cocoa, but it should be fairly easy to write one using NSMutableString, for example.

Comment: @LordPepito: I don't like this cast: `currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: ...`. The result of `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` is an `NSString` instance, not a `NSMutableString` instance. You cannot cast it that way.

Comment: Looks like others have answered your main question, so I'll assume you're ok there. But, you should be forewarned that the entire contents of a XML tag may not be contained in a single occurrence of `foundCharacters`. Especially for large strings, you may encounter a `didStartElement` followed by a series of `foundCharacters` and then terminated with a `didEndElement`. So, usually, you would initialize your `currentNodeContent` in `didStartElement` and then append to it in `foundCharacters`. Your code may work for shorter XML strings, but it's safer to use the procedure I outline here.

Comment: Yes its safer to use your method...I tested it and as I can see it retrieves all the characters in the xml file. I think its safier and more useful because Ive been trying to replace the " &lt,&gt, etc " but still didnt worked. I will use the method you guys proposed I think its far better, and then I will use the NSScanner to retrieve the characters I will use. Thanks everybody for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems have been outlined by Abhishek,  Rob and me. But I think it's worth to summarize it and show the correct solution.

The main problem is that `parser:foundCharacters:` is called several times for the `<description>` tag, each call providing a piece of the description.

The solution is to concatenate the pieces:

**XMLParser.h:**

```c
NSMutableString* currentNodeContent;
```

**XMLParser.m:**

```c
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (currentNodeContent == nil)
        currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity: 20];
    [currentNodeContent appendString: [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        currentFeed = [Feed alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"author"])
    {
        isStatus = NO;
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if (isStatus)
    {
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"description"])
        {
            currentTweet.description = currentNodeContent;
            NSLog(@"%@",currentNodeContent);

        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"])
        {
            currentTweet.content = currentNodeContent;
            NSLog(@"%@",currentNodeContent);

        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"link"])
        {
            currentFeed.WVUrl = currentNodeContent;
            NSLog(@"%@",currentNodeContent);
        }
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        [self.feeds addObject:currentFeed];
        currentFeed = nil;
        [currentNodeContent release];
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the Xml file is use of "&" Character.

Do one this just get the xml data in one string and then replace "&" with any unique string and then parse your xml.

While showing or use of xml data just check if the string you are getting contains the same unique string in it then replace that string with the "&".

Comment: Why should the `&` character be a problem? Wherever it appears in the sample XML, it is properly used a part of an XML entity (like `&gt;` or `&amp;`). All special characters of the embedded HTML are properly escaped. So the XML is - as far as I can tell - valid.

Comment: have you check the xml in the online xml validators?

Comment: Yes, I just checked it. It's valid.

Comment: hi got the problem. i parsed your xml and see the &lt; is for "<" and when you are parsing the xml due this symbol xml parser getting it as a new tag while parsing. When i parsed your xml i am getting 3 values in found characters delegate: "Este es mi blog 3",
    "<",
    "img src=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/blogspot/TUvAW/~4/URCV9ModTR0\" height=\"1\" width=\"1\"/",
    ">". Just replace the special characters coming in the xml it will parse properly.

Comment: It's an important point that `parser:foundCharacters` is called several times. This is probably the core of the problem. But your conclusion is wrong: Even if you replace the special characters, it might be called several times. The proper solution is the concatenate the strings.